# Can't ping between two Raspberry Pi 4s on WiFi running bookworm

Tags: networking, troubleshooting

I have two Raspberry Pi 4b's running bookworm with all updates. Something is wrong with the WiFi connection.

I can browse the internet but when I try to ping one from the other or vice versa, it just responds with destination host unreachable.

I rebuilt both systems from scratch, applied all updates, disabled ipv6. I can open websites, but still can't ping each other. there are no firewalls enabled on either system.

Both systems are on the same WiFi SSID and both have the same IP route:

I do not have access to the WiFi equipment so I cannot give any info about that. other systems on the same WiFi SSID can ping each other, but none can ping these 2 systems.

I appreciate any assistance I can get.

Ole.

As requested below, some clarifications.

The two systems are base installations of 2023-10-10-raspios-bookworm-arm64-full.img. The IP addresses are provided by dhcp.

```
# ------------- system #1-----------
Note: I had to remove "http://" from the 2 apt updates below because "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 8 links." on stackexchange.

$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Get:2 deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:3 deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]     
Get:4 deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main armhf Packages [83.7 kB]
Get:5 deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main arm64 Packages [86.1 kB]
Get:6 deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main Translation-en [50.8 kB]  
Hit:7 archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease                                               
Fetched 321 kB in 11s (29.8 kB/s)                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

$ ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:06:de:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:06:de:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.9.32.128/24 brd 10.9.32.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 604084sec preferred_lft 604084sec
    inet6 fd73:e237:e96e:6bd1:d83d:ae65:964e:25fd/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1582sec preferred_lft 1582sec
    inet6 fe80::a1ac:1640:98c7:5c70/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

 $ ip route
default via 10.9.32.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 10.9.32.128 metric 600 
10.9.32.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.32.128 metric 600 

$ ping google.ca
PING google.ca (172.217.13.163) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.217.13.163 (172.217.13.163): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=9.82 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.13.163 (172.217.13.163): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=11.2 ms
^C64 bytes from 172.217.13.163: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=12.6 ms

--- google.ca ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 10026ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.819/11.218/12.624/1.145 ms

$ ping 10.9.32.128 # this system
PING 10.9.32.128 (10.9.32.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.9.32.128: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.148 ms
64 bytes from 10.9.32.128: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.154 ms
64 bytes from 10.9.32.128: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.148 ms
^C
--- 10.9.32.128 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2048ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.148/0.150/0.154/0.003 ms

$ ping 10.9.32.76 # other system
PING 10.9.32.76 (10.9.32.76) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.9.32.128 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.9.32.128 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.9.32.128 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.9.32.76 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4099ms
pipe 4

# ------------- system #2-----------
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Hit:3 deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:4 archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease
Reading package lists... Done             
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:42:5d:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:42:5d:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.9.32.76/24 brd 10.9.32.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 537816sec preferred_lft 537816sec
    inet6 fd73:e237:e96e:6bd1:691e:3928:6d9c:3aeb/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1077sec preferred_lft 1077sec
    inet6 fe80::8763:c17c:ac66:5e5f/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip route
default via 10.9.32.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 10.9.32.76 metric 600 
10.9.32.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.32.76 metric 600 

$ ping google.ca
PING google.ca (172.217.13.163) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.217.13.163 (172.217.13.163): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=9.88 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.13.163 (172.217.13.163): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=14.4 ms
^C64 bytes from 172.217.13.163: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=14.3 ms

--- google.ca ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 10031ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.878/12.853/14.413/2.104 ms

$ ping 10.9.32.76 # this system
PING 10.9.32.76 (10.9.32.76) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.9.32.76: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.145 ms
64 bytes from 10.9.32.76: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.140 ms
64 bytes from 10.9.32.76: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.143 ms
^C
--- 10.9.32.76 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2044ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.140/0.142/0.145/0.002 ms

$ ping 10.9.32.128 # other system
PING 10.9.32.128 (10.9.32.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.9.32.76 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.9.32.76 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.9.32.76 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.9.32.128 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4098ms
pipe 3
```

Comment: I have not upgraded yet but someone else here observed that the networking service used by default on bullseye (`dhcpcd`) was replaced in bookworm with `NetworkManager`.  It's pretty well documented online, I think, since it has predominated on various big linux distros for a decade or so.  But I'm not a user and there is no telling what the RpiOS folks did with it...

Comment: @golidilocks: thanks for that tip. I will have to investigate networkmanager and see if there is something that I need to do that doesn't come in the standard installation of bookworm on rpi.

Comment: Your network seems to be OK and despite your claims to have disabled IPv6 (WHY?) it is allocated.

Comment: @milliways: I followed instructions from raspberrypi.org that was supposed to disable ipv6. The reason I tried to disable ipv6 was to prevent race conditions in mdns that would prevent me from use mdns to determine the ip address.

Comment: @milliways: If, as you say, the network seems to be ok, why can't I ping between the  2 rpi4s? I can ping to/from 10.9.32.181 and either 10.9.32.76 or 10.9.32.128, but not to/from 10.9.32.76 and 10.9.32.128 ?

Comment: You haven't provided sufficient detail. What router etc are you using? You claim "other systems on the same wifi ssid can ping each other" but have provided no evidence.

Comment: @milliways: I have no access to the routers or other networking equipment. how would I know what that equipment is? Do you really want me to provide evidence that "I can ping to/from 10.9.32.181 and either 10.9.32.76 or 10.9.32.128". why would I lie about that?

Comment: You say "I can browse the internet" and "The IP addresses are provided by dhcp" so you MUST have access to whatever is providing internet and DHCP - but haven't explained what this is. What is "10.9.32.181"? I am not accusing you of a lie but if you don't provide any detail no one can help - I am trying to get you to perform the basic diagnostic testing we would do.

Comment: If it is NOT isolation then the only other thing that blocks ping is firewalls or disable ICMP echo reply. And you mentioned that you followed a guide to disable IPv6, what guide URL/link please.

Comment: Have you disabled ICMP ECHO,  `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1` change the 1 to a 0 to enable it.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been feeling well and I am still working on gathering all the information asked for. I should have it ready by tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your WiFi network that has the "isolation" feature.

Some WiFi network equipment has "Wireless Client Isolation", this is a security feature so that WiFi devices can't reach each other on the same WiFi network.

Comment: I can ping to/from 10.9.32.181 and either 10.9.32.76 or 10.9.32.128, but not to/from 10.9.32.76 and 10.9.32.128. other users on the same ssid can communicate with other systems on that ssid. It is not a case of "Wireless Client Isolation"